# Angular: scope, how to set ng-repeat in a Directive

Tags: angularjs

I don't know how to send my "files" variable to my custom Directive:

```
app.directive('chooseImages', function() {
        var files = [{name: 'a', value: 'a.jpg'}, {name: 'b', value: 'b.jpg'}, {name: 'b', value: 'b.jpg'}];
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            template: '<ul><li ng-repeat="file in files">{{files}}</li></ul>',
        };
    })
```

I also tried setting "scope"

```
app.directive('chooseImages', function() {
        var files = [{name: 'a', value: 'a.jpg'}, {name: 'b', value: 'b.jpg'}, {name: 'b', value: 'b.jpg'}];
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            template: '<ul><li ng-repeat="file in files">{{files}}</li></ul>',
            scope: {
                files: "@"
            },
            link: function(scope, elements, attr) {

            }
        };
    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still have files defined inside your directive if you define your own private scope and assign the variable to it in your link function like so:

**DIRECTIVE**

```
myApp.directive('chooseImages', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        template: '<ul><li ng-repeat="file in files">{{files}}</li></ul>',
        scope: true,
        link: function(scope, elements, attr) {
            scope.files = [{name: 'a', value: 'a.jpg'}, {name: 'b', value: 'b.jpg'}, {name: 'b', value: 'b.jpg'}];

        }
    };
})
```

**HTML**

```
<div choose-images ></div>
```

Plunkr [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/j1QspT?p=preview)

Answer (score 2):

this will not work because "files" is not in the SCOPE.

```
app.directive('chooseImages', function() {
        var files = [{name: 'a', value: 'a.jpg'}, {name: 'b', value: 'b.jpg'}, {name: 'b', value: 'b.jpg'}];
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            template: '<ul><li ng-repeat="file in files">{{files}}</li></ul>',
        };
    })
```

this will work:

```
app.directive('chooseImages', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            template: '<ul><li ng-repeat="file in files">{{file | json}}</li></ul>',
            scope: {
                files: "="
            }
        };
    })
```

### HTML

```
<div chosse-images files="outerscopefiles" ng-init="outerscopefiles=[{name: 'a', value: 'a.jpg'}, {name: 'b', value: 'b.jpg'}, {name: 'b', value: 'b.jpg'}]">
```

Comment: ah...didn't know I had to declare files in the attrs

Comment: You do not need it. But you should in order to get a reusable component . The another answer, forces you to complicate things if a different image set is needed. Here ng-init is used to simplify the answer, in a practical case you should get it from "controller scope".